# Black specks from RO faucet after 24h purge

Tags: water, faucet, filter

[image: Black specs]
I'm concerned about black specks coming out of the reverse osmosis system faucet. I also noticed an unusual noise coming from the membranes unit which I have never heard before.

I have just installed the filter and have purged the system for 24h.

How can I identify or troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Sample before and after the filter again. Where the flecks are will tell you.

Comment: What does “purged the system for 24h” mean exactly? Was this done based on a manufacturer recommendation?

Comment: It sounds like your membrane is not sealing, verify your pressures as that is an easy way to tell if there is a problem if the pressure is below the rating of psi per membrane layer you may have a bad seal or split membrane

Comment: Yes, the 24-hour purge is recommended by the GE RO system manual after installation and before drinking the water. It involves keeping the faucet running for 24h.

Comment: I didn't notice the black specks coming from the regular non-RO faucet

Comment: @EdBeal I replaced the memberane unit and initiated the purge, will test tomorrow to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Replacing the membranes appears to have solved the problem.